# Interface builder file content missing

Tags: xcode, macos, ios6

Am a new bie to IOS development. While working with some sample apps, my mac restarted and after opening xcode i found one interface builder file .xib marked as red. Double click on it shows no content at all. I tried deleting and adding it back from xcode but its not working.
I dont see the file in the project directory too, but when i replace it with old file, it says

> an item with same name exists

but its not visible in finder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is a clean solution for this but a quick fix/workaround which worked for me is this:

Along with the error message 'an item with same name exists' you must be getting an id/number which is duplicated.
Open the xib file in any text editor (TextWrangler etc.). It is just an xml file.
Search for that number in the xib. You'll find multiple occurrences of that id.
Replace one of the occurrences with another number and make sure the new number you've added is not a duplicate.
Save this file and open in xcode. The error should be resolved.

Comment: well, now i dont find the file either in finder or xcode, but if copy the the old file with same name into the directory, it says 'an item with same name exists'

Comment: so do the same changes for the old file you copied. i hope when you say old file you just mean another copy with not many changes.

Comment: well, the changes are less in that specific file, were as the rest files have lot of changes, will replace those if thats the only solution left..  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click on one file in the project and it displays the **showinfinder** . Then it opens project folder in the finder. Check your file whether it is existing in that or not.